# Custom sorting in Python

Tags: python, lambda

I'm new to Python, thus the question,

I have the following list of list items,

```
[[0, 1], [2,3], [1,2], [4, 5], [3, 5]]
```

I want to sort this list in increasing order comparing the second item of each list first and then the first item

This is my code,

```
def sorting(a, b):
    if a[1] > b[1]:
        return 1
    elif a[1] == b[1]:
       if a[0] > b[0]:
            return 1
        else:
            return -1
    else:
        return 1
```

However can someone help me rewrite this using the sorted function with lambda and comprehensions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a Python dictionary by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse the order when the sort looks at them. Just don't alter the original list items.

sorted(l, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))

Answer (score 0):

You should use Python's built-in [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) method, it already has support for lambda comparisons.

```
l = [[0, 1], [2,3], [1,2], [4, 5], [3, 5]]
l = sorted(l, cmp=sorting)
```

Your comparison function is wrong if you want to sort in the way that you are talking about. There is no return zero case and the bottom `return 1` should be `return -1`. Also indentation error.

Comment: Can you explain your answer a bit, I want to sort the list on the basis of the second number and then the first. How's this code doing that?

Comment: @CodeMonkey Have you tried running the code, at all? It uses the function you defined in your question to sort the list.

Comment: Oasiscircle is doing that by calling the sorting function you already wrote.

Comment: I didn't realise the sorting was my sorting

Comment: @CodeMonkey Also note my edit to my answer, your comparison function does not work for what you want to achieve.